# .thenAccept to string

Tags: java, json, completable-future

Currently my code is the following:

```
client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
            .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
            .thenAccept(System.out::println)
            .join()
```

the line .thenAccept(System.out::println) prints a JSON query response from last.fm.

I'm trying to figure out what to replace System.out::println with to instead save the response to a String that I can then iterate through to define parts of an Album and Track object. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is `client`? Are you saying that `sendAsync` returns a `CompletableFuture`? If so, what's the payload type?

Comment: You use `thenApply`, giving it a function that converts the input to a string. Something like `thenAccept(object -> object.toString()).join()`

Comment: @ernest_k don’t confuse `thenApply` and `thenAccept`.

Comment: @Holger Right :) - Used the wrong method name in example

Answer (score 0):

The concrete solution does heavily depend in the return type of `HttpResponse::body`. Assuming the returned object is straight up a `String` you have multiple choices how to deal with it. One might be:

```
...thenAccept(HttpResponse::body)
.thenAccept( jsonString -> { /* save logic goes here*/})
.join();
```

I suggest learning more about lambdas and method references and all the different ways to handle them. E.g. you could also outsource the saving-logic to save the string into it's own method and then referenced it with  `this::saveJson`